# Deploy Rshiny App :Error Building Hunspell(2.7)

Tags: r, deployment, dplyr, shiny, hunspell

The code works properly in the RStudio IDE but when deploying the RShiny app it generates this error

```
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 499025532 failed: Error building image: Error building hunspell (2.7). Build exited with non-zero status: 1
```

I am a newbie and my App works on sentiment analysis based on text2vec package and also generates wordcloud.
Is there any way to overcome this?

Package dependencies for the app are:

```
>   package version source
  1 packrat 0.4.8-1   CRAN
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide your dependencies? Run rsconnect::appDependencies() and update your question!

Comment: I have included my app dependencies :